# Multivariable limit with polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Polar coordinates do not reveal the behaviour of $f(x,y)$ when studying

$$ \lim_{x^2 + y^2 \to \infty} \frac {xy}{e^{x^2y^2}} $$

In polar coordinates we have

$$ \lim_{r^2 \to \infty} \frac 12 \frac { r^2 \sin (2 \varphi ) }{ e^{ \frac 14 r^4 \sin^2 (2\varphi) } } $$

which goes to zero independently of $\varphi$. However by letting $y = \frac 1x$, we clearly see that the limit cannot exist. Why didn't polar coordinates work out and what other way than  letting $y = \frac 1x$ can we show that it does not exist?

Comment: What if $\sin(2\varphi)=1/r^2$?

Comment: Hm, interesting. That substitution is more or less equivalent to $y = 1/x$. I attempted to find an angle $\varphi$ such that the limit would degenerate but was unable to do so.

Answer (score 4):

But the issue is why polar coordinates can lead to error. In fact this is a recurrent misunderstanding. To explain it I turn to limits when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ (the same thing up to an inversion). The condition

*for all $\theta$ there exist $\lim_{\rho\to0}f(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta)$ and does not depend on $\theta$,*

only says that all limits along lines through the origin exist and coincide. This is not enough for the limit to exist, there could be different limits along paraboles, for instance (hyperbolas in a comment above). What is equivalent to the existence of a limit, say $L$, is

*for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that if $\ 0<\rho<\delta$,

then for all $0\le\theta<2\pi$ we have $\ |f(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta)-L|<\varepsilon.$*

In other words, what must be independent of $\theta$ is the rate of convergency $\delta$, besides the limit $l$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two hyperbolas
$$\gamma_\pm:\qquad y=\pm{1\over x}\quad(x>0)\ .$$
When $(x,y)\in\gamma_+$ then $f(x,y)={1\over e}$, and when $(x,y)\in\gamma_-$ then $f(x,y)=-{1\over e}$. Since both hyperbolas extends to infinity there are are points $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2$ arbitrarily large and $f(x,y)={1\over e}$, and there are other such points with $f(x,y)=-{1\over e}$. It follows that the envisaged limit cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: you can study the auxiliar function $z\mapsto z/\exp z^2$. Obviously, $z=xy$.

EDIT: do the limits on the subsets $x=0$ (or $y=0$, or $x=y$) and
$y={1\over\sqrt2 \,x}.$

Comment: So we are reducing to a single variable function and now let $u \to \infty$? This doesn't catch the special case where the limit degenerates.

Comment: The next step: possible values of $z=xy$ (and $z/\exp z^2$) when $x^2+y^2=R$?

Comment: Well z can take on arbitrary values since x and y get arbitrarily large (either negative or positive), so what can we really conclude?

Comment: *And* arbitrary small.

Comment: Well sure, in that case $z \to 0$ and therefore the limit is $0$ since $e^0 = 1$. What am I not realizing here?

Comment: $z=xy$ can take small *and* large values when $x^2+y^2=R$. And $z/\exp z^2$... (draw the graph)

Comment: Yes that auxiliary function approaches zero as z becomes sufficiently large and goes to zero as z becomes arbitrarily small.  Furthermore, it assumes it's maximum value for $\sqrt 2 /2 $. Not realizing it yet...

Comment: When $(x,y)$ varies in $x^2+y^2=R$, $z/\exp z^2$ **varies** from 0 to $\sqrt2/2$.

Comment: Sure. Having another look, I see that it varies from $- \sqrt 2 /2$ and $\sqrt 2 / 2$. I do not see where this realization is to lead us..

Comment: The function $\frac{xy}{e^{x^2y^2}}$ *varies* in an interval without approaching to a supposed limit when $x^2+y^2$ is arbitrarily large.

Comment: Except it does. When $x^2 + y^2$ get really large, it approaches zero. There are multivariable functions that *vary* in an interval but still have an existing limit, so I do not how see the property of *varying* is the one from which we can infer the non-existence of the limit.

Comment: Re-read the definition of limit.

Comment: We want for all $\epsilon$ that $|f(x,y) - L| < \epsilon$ that there exists a $\delta$ such that $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > \delta$.

Comment: If $\lim$ exists $f$ will vary in *smaller* and *smaller* intervals.